# psexec - Execute program on a remote computer: Access denied. Meaning of parameters in command?

Tags: remote-access, psexec

We want to run executables on a remote computer - So, if I start the program on computer A, it actually runs on computer B. (Executables will be written in C#, and a similar process would be helpful for LabView programs, in case that matters)

Googling brought up psexec, but I can't figure out how to get it working.

I've tried the command:

```
psecec -i -s -d -c -f \\remoteComputer -u remoteAdmin -p password c:\testfolder\test.exe
```

For remoteComputer, I've tried both the network name and the IP address of the remote computer. remoteAdmin/password, I've been typing in the name of the admin account and its password. The filepath is the full filepath to the program on the running computer. I've tried it as the full filepath to the program on the remote computer as well.

In any case, I don't think it's getting to the point where it looks for the program to execute - I just get "Couldn't access remoteComputer: Access is denied" messages.

I suspect I lack some basic knowledge of how remote access works. Some examples used domain\remoteAdmin as the username, but I have no idea what 'domain' should be.

Computers are running windows 7 and windows XP. We could upgrade the XP computers if it doesn't work otherwise. I've only tested running the command from 7, and I've used both XP and 7 computers as the remote computer.

Comment: starting to type `psex...` on google brings `psexec eaccess denied` as 1st autocomplete. Have you looked at these results? The first one is a question here and I vote to close this as it's duplicate.

Comment: I haven't tried some of those yet. I guess they got lost in me looking at different solutions. I will see if they solve the issue.

Comment: I stopped getting access errors after following the first step in the linked question. I can start a program from one windows 7 computer on another windows 7 computer. It looks like there's some other issue with the XP computers, though - I haven't been able to start a program on them yet.

Comment: I thought I should add, in case it affects anyone else: The issue with the XP computers was because we have XP Home computers, which don't allow admin sharing (Which PsExec uses)